# adding value to text box on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert an address into an input field upon clicking a button that is its sibling.

HTML

```
 <label for="to">To:</label>
 <input type="text" id="to" name="to" required="required" placeholder="An address" size="30" />
 <a id="to-link" href="#" class="button">Get my position</a>
 <a id="to-home" href="#" class="button">Home</a>

 <label for="from">From:</label>
 <input type="text" id="from" name="from" required="required" placeholder="Another address" size="30" />
 <a id="from-link" href="#" class="button">Get my position</a>
 <a id="from-home" href="#" class="button">Home</a>
```

Jquery

```
 jQuery("#from-home, #to-home").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      jQuery(this).prev("input").val("123 my street, 12345 Gotham");

    });
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I don't get anything if I `console.log(jQuery(this));` Sorry if this is a dumb question I'm just starting to get my head around "this" (or at least I thought I was.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prev() looks for the previous item not previous items. since previous item of your `$(this)` is `<a>`, it wont be setting your input field. In that case, you can either do:

```
$(this).prev().prev("input").val("123 my street, 12345 Gotham");
```

which I do not recommend. Better way of doing this would be by adding wrapper for your address groups:

```
<div>
  <label for="to">To:</label>
  <input type="text" id="to" name="to" required="required" placeholder="An address" size="30" /> <a id="to-link" href="#" class="button">Get my position</a>
  <a id="to-home" href="#" class="button">Home</a>

</div>
<div>
  <label for="from">From:</label>
  <input type="text" id="from" name="from" required="required" placeholder="Another address" size="30" /> <a id="from-link" href="#" class="button">Get my position</a>
  <a id="from-home" href="#" class="button">Home</a>
</div>
```

and for your javascript:

```
$("#from-home, #to-home").click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).siblings("input").val("123 my street, 12345 Gotham");
});
```

Here you can see the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/436qA/

Answer (score 1):

If you introduce two outer `DIV`s to your markup, then you can use the jQuery `.prevAll()` function, like this:

Markup:

```
<div>
    <label for="to">To:</label>
    <input type="text" id="to" name="to" required="required" placeholder="An address" size="30" /> <a id="to-link" href="#" class="button">Get my position</a>
    <a id="to-home" href="#" class="button">Home</a>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="from">From:</label>
    <input type="text" id="from" name="from" required="required" placeholder="Another address" size="30" /> <a id="from-link" href="#" class="button">Get my position</a>
    <a id="from-home" href="#" class="button">Home</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery("#from-home, #to-home").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    jQuery(this).prevAll("input").val("123 my street, 12345 Gotham");
});
```

Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v47pR/).

Read [jQuery .prevAll() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, it was a tossup between yours and the answer I choose. Both work so I went with the first come. Unless `.prevAll()`is more efficient?

Comment: @mantis - no worries, glad you got an answer that works for you. :-) Feel free to up-vote my answer if you have not already.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the single previous `<input>`, you can use the .prevAll() command:

```
$("#from-home, #to-home").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $(this).prevAll("input").eq(0).val("123 my street, 12345 Gotham");
});
```

The `.eq(0)` reduces the matched elements you are looking for (thus, the second Home button will only find the `<input>` tag right before it).

Comment: Interesting approach.  Given the order that the elements are returned, the one you want will always be first.  Probably not a great idea if there are a large number of siblings since it will have to search through them all and then get filtered to just one.

Comment: Yes, but this will also ensure that it only changes one of the input fields, rather than `.sibling()` or `.prevAll()` without `.eq(0)` which could get multiple ones

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `this` should be fine.  Your issue is with `prev`.  `prev` only gets the preceding sibling.  In this case, the preceding sibling is a anchor and not an `input`.  As a result, `.prev("input")` will not find anything since the previous sibling does not match the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Extending off of Jame's answer

> "Your usage of this should be fine. Your issue is with prev. prev only gets the preceding sibling. In this case, the preceding sibling is a anchor and not an input. As a result, .prev("input") will not find anything since the previous sibling does not match the selector."

.prev()'s selector is exclusionary. In this specific case you can daisy-chain prev() to select what you want.

```
jQuery("#from-home, #to-home").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  jQuery(this).prev().prev().val("123 my street, 12345 Gotham");

});
```

Will allow you to select what you want. What makes more sense to me, however, is to select the element by id.